# how to use firebug in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, firebug-lite

A tutorial I'm doing uses firebug lite in IE8 to run jquery code, inspect the DOM, etc.  I have a link reference to firebug lite so that I can use it in IE8.  I know I can use firebug in FF and I know about the inspect tool in IE8, however, since firebug lite is supposed to be compatible with IE8, I'd like to use it in IE8.  Can anyone help me out?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you add that snippet to your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work by just adding this script to the  of your document.

Just note that there's a recent bug that prevents that little icon to appear at the lower-right corner of the screen:

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4891

Just press F12 to open up the UI. If you have any questions, feel free to contact us at:
http://groups.google.com/group/firebug