# Is there a way to troubleshoot my Rails javascript application.js in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8

I have an application that works famously in Firefox, Safari, and Opera, but fails in IE 8. It give a really stupid error message:

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 350
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://evokat.localhost.com/javascripts/application.js?1343661671
```

All that does is point to the first letter of this line (which is indented 2 spaces):

```
partslist = $("#partslist").dataTable({
              "bPaginate": false,
              "bLengthChange": false,
              "bFilter": false,
              "bSort": false,
              "bInfo": false });
```

Naturally, my 2 largest customers use Internet Explorer 8. That error message tells me absolutely nothing, and I am unable to locate a Firebug-like debugging environment for IE. What is the next step I should take please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some interesting discussions on installing developer toolbar / firebug with IE, check them out , probably could get a hint

[how to use firebug in ie8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719848/how-to-use-firebug-in-ie8)

https://superuser.com/questions/43653/whats-ie8-equivalent-of-chrome-and-firefox-firebug-inspect-element

[How to install Firebug lite IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716164/how-to-install-firebug-lite-ie8)

Comment: Really worked great, especially logging to console. Thanks Sameera.

Comment: Hi @MFer, glad it help, no offence but IE is a pain in the A** :D